# HTML & CSS with bootstrap / Simple question why the two container overlapped in my code

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used bootstrap to create the navbar and i want to add some extra effect on it.

I want to make a sticky navbar with bootstrap, with the effect of adding a red underline for each `<a>` tag. But when I scroll down, the red underline effect is disabled and the navbar and the numbers overlapped.... Can anyone tell me why?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   /*when this file has been loaded, execute the function*/
                $(window).scroll(function(){ /*when the page is scrolled, execute the function*/
                    if($(window).scrollTop()>-60){   /*Question? why need if, can it remove if??*/
                        $('.my-navbar').addClass('navbar-scroll');
                    }
                    else{
                        $('.my-navbar').removeClass('nav-scroll');
                    }
                });
            });
```

```css
body{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        
    }
    
    .col-md-8{
        font-size: 120px;
    }
    .menu{
        width:90%;
        position: relative;
    
    
    }
    
    .my-navbar{
        width:100%;
        padding: 20px 20px;
        background-color: white;
        position: relative;
        top:20px;
        left:0;
        box-shadow:0px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    
    .nav-item .nav-link{
        font-size: 15px;
        color:black;
        font-weight:400;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin:0px 10px;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .nav-item .nav-link:after{
        position: absolute;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;
        width:100%;
        height:2px;
        transform:scaleX(0);    
        transition: 0.5s;
        content:"";             
        transform-origin:left;
        background-color: brown;
    }
    
    .nav-item .nav-link:hover:after{
        transform-origin:right;
        transform: scaleX(1); /*影響線長？*/
    
    }
    
    .navbar-scroll{
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7) ;
        padding: 5px 20px;
        transition: 0.5s;
        animation: scroll 0.6s 1;
    }
    
    @keyframes scroll{
        0%{transform:translateY(-100%);}
        100%{transform:translateY(0%);}
    }
    
    .navbar-brand{
        text-transform: capitalize;
        font-size: 35px;
        color: #2f3542;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

<header>
    <div class="container-fluid menu">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg my-navbar">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-8">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                3
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                5
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                6
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                7
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                8
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or working demo on something like codesandbox.io ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `.navbar-scroll`'s background-color has a transparency value of `0.7`, which makes the content shine through it when you scroll down. Just change the background-color to `white` or the transparency value to `1` (`background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1)`).

Concerning the red underlines on the nav links: They *do* appear on hover (?)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   /*when this file has been loaded, execute the function*/
                $(window).scroll(function(){ /*when the page is scrolled, execute the function*/
                    if($(window).scrollTop()>-60){   /*Question? why need if, can it remove if??*/
                        $('.my-navbar').addClass('navbar-scroll');
                    }
                    else{
                        $('.my-navbar').removeClass('nav-scroll');
                    }
                });
            });
```

```css
body{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        
    }
    
    .col-md-8{
        font-size: 120px;
    }
    .menu{
        width:90%;
        position: relative;
    
    
    }
    
    .my-navbar{
        width:100%;
        padding: 20px 20px;
        background-color: white;
        position: relative;
        top:20px;
        left:0;
        box-shadow:0px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    
    .nav-item .nav-link{
        font-size: 15px;
        color:black;
        font-weight:400;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin:0px 10px;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .nav-item .nav-link:after{
        position: absolute;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;
        width:100%;
        height:2px;
        transform:scaleX(0);    
        transition: 0.5s;
        content:"";             
        transform-origin:left;
        background-color: brown;
    }
    
    .nav-item .nav-link:hover:after{
        transform-origin:right;
        transform: scaleX(1); /*影響線長？*/
    
    }
    
    .navbar-scroll{
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
        padding: 5px 20px;
        transition: 0.5s;
        animation: scroll 0.6s 1;
    }
    
    @keyframes scroll{
        0%{transform:translateY(-100%);}
        100%{transform:translateY(0%);}
    }
    
    .navbar-brand{
        text-transform: capitalize;
        font-size: 35px;
        color: #2f3542;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

<header>
    <div class="container-fluid menu">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg my-navbar">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-8">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                3
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                5
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                6
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                7
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                8
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update my-navbar class css

```
.my-navbar{
    width:100%;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    top:20px;
    left:0;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1) !important;
}
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){   /*when this file has been loaded, execute the function*/
            $(window).scroll(function(){ /*when the page is scrolled, execute the function*/
                if($(window).scrollTop()>-60){   /*Question? why need if, can it remove if??*/
                    $('.my-navbar').addClass('navbar-scroll');
                }
                else{
                    $('.my-navbar').removeClass('nav-scroll');
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}

.col-md-8{
    font-size: 120px;
}
.menu{
    width:90%;
    position: relative;


}

.my-navbar{
    width:100%;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    top:20px;
    left:0;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1) !important;

}

.nav-item .nav-link{
    font-size: 15px;
    color:black;
    font-weight:400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin:0px 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav-item .nav-link:after{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:2px;
    transform:scaleX(0);    
    transition: 0.5s;
    content:"";             
    transform-origin:left;
    background-color: brown;
}

.nav-item .nav-link:hover:after{
    transform-origin:right;
    transform: scaleX(1); /*影響線長？*/

}

.navbar-scroll{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7) ;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    animation: scroll 0.6s 1;
}

@keyframes scroll{
    0%{transform:translateY(-100%);}
    100%{transform:translateY(0%);}
}

.navbar-brand{
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #2f3542;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<header>
<div class="container-fluid menu">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg my-navbar">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-8">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            3
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            4
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            5
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            6
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            7
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            8
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```